# Iterating over (x,y) positions of a grid using functional programming methods

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I want to iterate over positions `(x, y)` in a 2-dimensional grid and call a function for each position (providing `x` and `y` as parameters). I know how this can be done using `for` loops, but I'd like to write this using functional programming methods such that I can later take advantage of libraries like Rayon. I've managed to build a functional version, but it seems complicated and I wanted to ask whether there's a cleaner way to achieve this.

Here's a small example of computing the maximum sum of all 2x2 patches in a grid:

```
use std::cmp::max;

const WIDTH: usize = 4;
const HEIGHT: usize = 3;

type Grid = [[u32; WIDTH]; HEIGHT];

fn main() {
    let grid: Grid = [
        [1, 3, 5, 8], 
        [3, 9, 4, 2], 
        [3, 4, 5, 0],
    ];
                          
    let coords = (0..WIDTH - 1).flat_map(|x| (0..HEIGHT - 1).map(move |y| (x, y)));
    let max_sum = coords.map(|(x, y)| sum_2x2(x, y, &grid)).max().unwrap();
    println!("Max 2x2 patch: {}", max_sum);
}

fn sum_2x2(x: usize, y: usize, grid: &Grid) -> u32 {
    [
        grid[y][x],
        grid[y][x + 1],
        grid[y + 1][x],
        grid[y + 1][x + 1],
    ]
    .iter()
    .sum()
}
```

The line `let coords = (0..WIDTH - 1).flat_map(|x| (0..HEIGHT - 1).map(move |y| (x, y)));` seems pretty complex for such a simple task. In Python, I'd do the following to get the positions (which I think is much cleaner):

```py
>>> from itertools import product
>>> product(range(HEIGHT-1), range(WIDTH-1))
```

Is there a better way to write this or do I just need to get used to it?

Comment: Well-made question, might find a better home on CodeReview though.

Comment: I'm afraid this is offtopic for Stackoverflow, but I can recommend itertools for this job. https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/macro.iproduct.html

Comment: Keep in mind that example code on [CodeReview.SE] is off-topic. So make sure not to express your code as an example, but instead explicitly mention that you're looking for the maximum in a `[[u32; WIDTH]; HEIGHT]` array, found a solution, but feel like there should be a more functional way. And keep in mind that cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: Your `-1` in your iterator seems incorrect, seeing as how `..` already doesn't include the upper bound.

Comment: @Shepmaster I thought so too until I noticed that `sum_2x2` goes to `x+1` and `y+1`

Comment: @Jmb then the Python equivalent (`range(WIDTH)`) seems incorrect.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, the Python seems wrong

Comment: Yep, the python code was off by one. I just fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @hellow pointed out in the comments, there's an [`iproduct`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/macro.iproduct.html) macro in the [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate that does what I want. Using it, my code can be rewritten like this:

```
use itertools::iproduct;
...
let coords = iproduct!(0..WIDTH - 1, 0..HEIGHT - 1);
...
```

That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to everyone who commented / posted answers here.

*PS: If you want to use an itertools iterator with rayon, you can do this by using the [`par_bridge`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.3/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelBridge.html#tymethod.par_bridge) method, e.g. `iproduct!(0..WIDTH - 1, 0..HEIGHT - 1).par_iter();`. Took me a while to figure that out since `par_iter` and `into_par_iter` don't work.*

Answer (score 4):

You can possibly simplify the code with one of the loop comprehension crates like [`map_for`](https://crates.io/crates/map_for) or [`mdo`](https://crates.io/crates/mdo).
For example with `map_for`:

```
let max_sum = map_for!(
    move;
    x <- 0..WIDTH-1;
    y <- 0..HEIGHT-1;
    => sum_2x2(x, y, &grid)
).max().unwrap();
```

I haven't tried it with Rayon, but since `map_for` is simply syntax sugar for a sequence of calls to `map` and `flat_map` and works with any type that implements those functions, it should work with Rayon as well.

Full disclosure: I am the author of the `map_for` crate.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [`cartesian_product`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product) from the Itertools crate, which has many convenient methods involving iterators.

```
use itertools::Itertools;

(0..WIDTH-1).cartesian_product(0..HEIGHT-1).map(|(x, y)| sum_2x2(x, y, &grid)).max()
```